# what does single colon mean in cmd script except for using as a label?

Tags: cmd

As we all know, single colon ":" can be used as a label and referred by "GOTO" statement, but in the following code I don't know what does ":" mean here, can you help me :)

```
set "str=!str:Mode_1=%_MODE%!" 2>nul
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

From the `set /?` help message:

> Environment variable substitution has been enhanced as follows:
>
> ```
> %PATH:str1=str2%
> ```
>
> would expand the PATH environment variable, substituting each
>   occurrence of "str1" in the expanded result with "str2".  "str2" can
>   be the empty string to effectively delete all occurrences of "str1"
>   from the expanded output.  "str1" can begin with an asterisk, in which
>   case it will match everything from the beginning of the expanded
>   output to the first occurrence of the remaining portion of str1.

So `!str:Mode_1=%_MODE%!` will replace any instance of "Mode_1" in `str` with the value of the variable `%_MODE%`.  (the exclamation marks are being used for delayed expansion of `str`)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So detailed!

Answer (score 1):

The colon in the `set` command is used for string substitution. See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshpoley/archive/2011/06/03/batch-file-string-substitution-with-nested-environment-variables.aspx). The line that you gave still seems quite cryptic and doesn't quite match the examples of string substitution that I was able to find online.

Comment: Thank  you for your answer! I got it!